# android wifi api issue with 3.1

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I want to start my activity when my wifi will be switch on so that I call my activity when WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION. It will be working fine with 2.3(Gingerbread) samsung tap but same program won't work in 3.1(Honeycomb)samsung tap.guide why such type of issue will be happen here is my hole code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that listens for updates for the
 * ExampleAppWidgetProvider. This BroadcastReceiver starts off disabled, and we
 * only enable it when there is a widget instance created, in order to only
 * receive notifications when we need them.
 */
public class WIFIBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String packageName = "com.example.wifi";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED,
                    false)) {
                Log.d(packageName, "WIFI Connected");
                if (context != null) {

                    Intent ssIntent = new Intent(context,
                            com.example.wifi.Activity.class);
                    ssIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(ssIntent);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(packageName, "WIFI Connection was Lost");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'mot sure exactly what you issue is but it sounds like it has something to do with your ROM, if it's rooted or not, etc.

Another possibility is the API you're using. Does HC require a different version than GB?

I don't think it's your code, so if you can't figure it out, try providing info about the difference between the tab and phone (besides the obvious).

Just a hunch, so I'm sorry if it's way off base.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the issue you are facing. Would humbly suggest trying an alternative:

You could register for WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION intent and then in onReceive(), call getConnectionInfo(). The NetworkInfo.DetailedState class should provide (a more detailed) information on the whether IP address is available following which your activity could be started.